# how do I destroy Params GET or POST when I input to another Form?

Tags: php

```
<form id="form3" name="form3" method="get" action="">
<tr>
<td align="left" ><input name="page" type="text" id="page" size="5" value="<?php echo $pageNumView; ?>"/></td> 
</tr>
</form>
<form id="form4" name="form4" method="post" action="">
<tr>
<td width="84%"><input name="iddetails" type="text" id="iddetails" size="20" value="<?php echo $rows['product_id']; ?>"/> </td> 
</tr>
</form>
```

I have 2-Forms. I wanted to delete `$_GET['page']` in Form3 whenever I input on 'iddetails' in form4.
I tried using `unset($_GET['page']);` i can see it working using a debugger trace & deleted the params 'page'. 
But when I tried using Form4 Input again, `$_GET['page']` is still there and was not totally deleted.
So how do I delete the Params 'Page' in form3 if I input at 'iddetails' form4?

I have read about this POST-REDIRECT-GET solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the action so the $_GET value is not set:

```
 <form id="form3" name="form3" method="get" action="">
<tr>
<td align="left" ><input name="page" type="text" id="page" size="5" value="<?php echo $pageNumView; ?>"/></td> 
</tr>
</form>
<form id="form4" name="form4" method="post" action="yourform.php">
<tr>
<td width="84%"><input name="iddetails" type="text" id="iddetails" size="20" value="<?php echo $rows['product_id']; ?>"/> </td> 
</tr>
</form>
```

or do it like this:

```
if( isset( $_POST['iddetails']) && isset( $_GET['page'])){
   $_GET['page'] = 0; //Set it to whatever you like.
}
```

My question is: why is it a problem when the $_GET['page'] is set? You can simply igore it in your code when $_POST['iddetails'] is set?

Comment: Actually, I had this similar idea by using logical operators as a solution, if 'page' params can't be deleted. I was just curious if there is a way to delete the params since i tried using unset() & didn't work. Everytime i refresh the webpage, the 'page' is still there. Answer to your Question: The 'page' (& 'direction' w/c i didn't mention) is used to jump/scroll on mysql database & 'iddetails' is used when the user tries to edit 'product_id'. So whenever the user tries to edit 'product_id', the 'page'=$pagenumview (webpage scroll)is affected and UPDATES the wrong database. Anyway,many thnx.

Comment: Thanks again to all your effort of answering my problem. I really appreciate it. I found my own solution. StackOverflow website is really a big help... More Power!

Answer (score 0):

If both your forms are on the same web page, every time you refresh the page for form4, the $_GET for form3 will also get set, as the value of element 'page' comes from the server-side variable $pageNumView.

Moreover, you don't need to have POST just to get rid of the GET. Also, if you don't need a key in $_GET, just unset it after its use.